# Why is my bash prompt getting bugged when I browse the history?

Tags: bash, command-history, prompt

Often when I start looking at history of commands some of the characters from a command displayed aren't erased, for example:

What's happening:

```
prompt$ some_command
prompt$ some_commanother_command
```

What should have happened:

```
prompt$ some_command
prompt$ another_command
```

I can't erase those characters and bash ignores them when executing the command. They also disappear when a new prompt is being displayed (after pressing `Enter` for example).

I asked other people who work on Linux at my workplace and they said that they have that problem sometimes too, but they didn't have an idea on how solve that issue.

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm using guake. Here is my `PS1`:

```
\e[0;31m\u \A ${PWD##*/}\e[0;32m$(parse_git_branch)\e[0;31m$\e[m
```

where `parse_git_branch` is

```
parse_git_branch () {
    git name-rev HEAD 2> /dev/null | sed 's#HEAD\ \(.*\)# (\1)#'
}
```

As far as I know my colleagues have that problem even with less "fancy" PS1.

Comment: As mentioned already, non-printable sequences need to be wrapped with `\[...\]` in order to let bash calculate the correct length of the prompt. However, what also seems to be important from my testing is if you have a multi-line prompt, the `\r\n` sequence should *not* go in the `\[...\]` wrapping.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use `\[...\]` around the parts of PS1 that have length 0. It helps bash to get the length of the prompt right. Even with this measure, your command line can get spoiled when using multibyte characters (at least mine does). Hitting <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> also helps in such cases (but clears the screen at the same time).

Comment: I modified my bashrc and now I have `PS1="\\[\e[0;31m\\]\u \A \${PWD##*/}\\[\e[0;32m\\]\$(parse_git_branch)\\[\e[0;31m\\]$\\[\e[m\\] "`. Kinda hard to understand when I'm looking at it but it seems that it helped.

Comment: @korda I find using single quotes to remove the backslash doubling helps a lot.  I also set the character sequences to variables, which helps a bit as well.  My `PS1` looks like `PS1="${reset_color}[${cyan}\A${reset_color}]${reset_color}${user_color}\u@\h(\l)${white}:${blue}\W${reset_color}[${yellow}\$?${reset_color}]${white}"'\$'"${reset_color} "`

Comment: Ctrl-L only __rarely__ helped me. But typing `$ reset` directly on the command line did the trick and brought my `bash` back to useable state.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: right at the beginning, `\e[0m` isn't enclosed in `\[...\]`.

Comment: Is there a bash bug report? This is a bug which has wasted too much of my time, and should be fixable in general (without `PS1` hacks).

Comment: @dhardy: What exactly is the bug?

Comment: @choroba that bash does some odd behaviour given incorrect `PS1` instead of either doing the right thing or stopping with an error. It's a bit like the "undefined behaviour" in C etc.: allowed, but not likable, except in this case it should be fixable.

Comment: @dhardy: Do you mean checking each character coming from various parts of PS1 for its non-zero length? Interesting idea.

Comment: This answer resolved my issue with a multiline prompt full of functions. I forgot to enclose 2 \e[xm with the \\[...\\]

Comment: Thanks very much. I believe this fixed my issue. Is there a reference for this? Unfortunately these character sequences are not very googleable

Answer (score 15):

You need to make sure you are escaping all of the non-printable characters.

Good

```
PS1="\[\e[36m\]\W ⇨ \[\e[m\] "
```

Bad

```
PS1="\[\e[36m\]\W ⇨ [\e[m\] "
```

Comment: I'm getting this `\[\e[36m\]\W ⇨ \[\e[m\] \[\033[m\033[1;37m\]\u\[\033[m\[\e[0;36m\]\] \w$(prompt_git)\n\[\033[m\033[1;37m\]$ \[\033[m\]` as my prompt. U update PS1 in `.bash_profile` to the above but that didn't worked.