# Why does this PS1 value cause unexpected behaviour?

Tags: bash, command-history, prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my bash prompt getting bugged when I browse the history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/why-is-my-bash-prompt-getting-bugged-when-i-browse-the-history)

I have set my `PS1` variable in `.bashrc` to be the following:

`PS1='\e[35m[\W]:\e[0m '`

It achieved what it was intended to (change the color of the prompt which displays `cwd` inside `[]` and before `:`), but when I search through my command history, sometimes parts of commands that I cycle over become attached to the prompt. For example:

```
[~]: echo "something"
something
[~]: date
Sun Nov 18 17:07:54 PST 2012
[~]: sudo apt-get install vim
...
```

Now, say I want to return to my `echo "something"` command, I press up and get

```
[~]: sudo apt-get install vim
```

I press up again and this happens

```
[~]: sudo apt-date
```

up again

```
[~]: sudo apt-echo "something"
```

and if I delete everything on the command line by pressing backspace, it deletes all the way back to

```
[~]: sudo apt-
```

It has no affect on the command. For example, the line `[~]: sudo apt-date` will still print the output of `date` etc. Why is this happening and how can I achieve the desired prompt without the side effects?

Comment: Which terminal program are you using?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What's going on is that Bash is getting confused about the number of printing characters in your prompt. It sends cursor positioning sequences to the terminal to position the cursor properly for doing command history and such. It needs to have a good idea of where the cursor actually is after printing the prompt.

Try setting your prompt to this:

```
PS1='\[\e[35m\][\W]:\[\e[0m\] '
```

It should now work as expected.

The `\[` and `\]` pairs tell Bash that the stuff between them is a non-printing escape sequence and won't actually move the cursor forward. It will then correctly guess the cursor position and do a proper replacement when going through your command history.

This information can be found in the info node [`(bash)Printing a Prompt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Printing-a-Prompt.html).

**Edit:** In newer versions of bash this has changed to [`(bash)Controlling the Prompt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html).

Comment: You are a GOD! This solved my command history problem.

Comment: @stariz77: No, not even a demigod really. ;-) I'm glad it fixed your problem though. Do you know how to get to info nodes to read them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by info nodes? If it's just a synonym for `man` pages, then yes.

Comment: @stariz77, no, [info (aka Texinfo)](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) is the standard documentation format of the GNU project.  It generally contains much more detail than a manpage.  Try typing the command `info bash` (or `info info` to learn about `info` itself).

Comment: @stariz77 - And the command to get right to the mentioned info node would be `info '(bash)Printing a Prompt'`.

Comment: If the length of the prompt changes dynamically `PROMPT_COMMAND` can be used. See http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/bash/dynamic-prompt-with-git-and-ansi-colors/ for an example.

Comment: Is this something specific to Bash / PS1, or is it good practice to *always* wrap ANSI color codes with `\[` and `\]` (even outside of Bash)?