# bash - complex prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

I want to have really complex prompt. It should contains login, computer name, date, time, working directory, result of last command and new line symbol. I want to color each item as well. So I inserted into my `.bashrc` some kind of monster like this one:

```
# login and computer name
PS1='[\e[1;37m\]\u\e[m\]@\e[1;32m\]\h\e[m\]] '
# date, time and working directory
PS1=$PS1'[\e[1;34m\]\D{%Y-%m-%d} \e[1;35m\]\t\e[m\]] \e[1;33m\]\w\e[m\] '
# result of last command and command prompt in new line
PS1=$PS1'\e[1;31m\]${?#0}\e[m\]\n \e[1;36m\]\$\e[m\] '
```

I do know it is terrible solution, but I have too little experience with bash to improve this. But this is not the only one problem.

```
 $ aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bash: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: command not found...
```

After the last `a` I pressed `Home` key, but visual caret didn't go to the beginning of the command. As you can see, actual caret went to the beginning. Why this occurred? How can I improve my command prompt in my `.bashrc`?

---

### Update:

After using @Groxxda advice, I've got one another problem. My `.bashrc` `PS1` definition looks like [this one](http://pastebin.com/EZDn6VkP). Described issue doesn't occur now. But if in my command history I have `ls` and before this I have `cat script.sh`, and if I push arrow up twice, I have got command like `cat scls` and buffer has only two signs (only `ls`). Why this occurs? How can I manage this?

Comment: Check your `\[` `\]` escapes. This tells bash that the content between does not print visible characters. You should put them around the color codes.

Comment: works great! why didn't you answered but only commented?

Comment: @Groxxda yes, this is the answer - so make it a full answer

Comment: I've got one another problem. After upgrade by @Groxxda, my `.bashrc` PS1 definition looks like this one: http://pastebin.com/EZDn6VkP. Described issue doesn't occurs now. But if in my command history I have `ls` and before this I have `cat script.sh`, and if I push arrow twice, I have got command like `cat scls` and buffer has only two signs (only `ls`). Why this occurs? How can I manage this?

Comment: The original question is a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/why-is-my-bash-prompt-getting-bugged-when-i-browse-the-history. I'm not sure I understand the duplicate, but it looks like it's still the same issue: you need to wrap all zero-width parts of the prompt in `\[…\]`.

Comment: Your unescaped sequences are still breaking your term... You are better off starting with a *simple* prompt, and building it up gradually, as you understand how it works.

Comment: @jasonwryan, which one sequences are still unescaped? I want to have format `[login@computername]`... etc.

Comment: `[login@hostname]` is the basic prompt: see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Regular_user

Comment: Ok, but there are still no colors. If I understand well, I have to escape all color tags, because they don't print any sign, but only send information about color and caret is missed. So I did this: http://pastebin.com/4exfRRN9. But there are still two missing fields... What should I also escape?

Comment: Try removing the duplicate `\]`s in your prompt. Also which fields are missing?

Comment: Ok. your solution works. But I don't know why... but anyway - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose invisible parts of the prompt text in `\[` and `\]`.
That is used by `bash` to calculate the length of the complete prompt, so it can determine where the cursor will be after printing it.
For example, ANSI color escape codes are invisible - they change the color for text that will be output later. They need to be enclosed like this:

`\e[1;35m` becomes `\[\e[1;35m\]`

In your update, you write that this helped, but that there is another problem:
the screen does not get cleared at the right locations if you use the history with <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

This is just another aspect of the first problem: The calculation of the prompt text length is wrong.

Let's take a look at the corrected prompt text from your link:

```
# login and computer name                                                      
PS1='[\e[\[1;37m\]\]\u\e[\[m\]\]@\e[\[1;32m\]\]\h\e[\[m\]\]] '                  
# date, time                                                                    
PS1=$PS1'[\e[\[1;34m\]\]\D{%Y-%m-%d} \e[\[1;35m\]\]\t\e[\[m\]\]] '              
# working directory and result of last command                                  
PS1=$PS1'\e[\[1;33m\]\]\w\e[\[m\]\] \e[\[1;31m\]\]${?#0}\e[\[m\]\]\n '          
# command prompt                                                                
PS1=$PS1'\e[\[1;36m\]\]\$\e[\[m\]\] '
```

The problem is that the `\[` and `\]` are not enclosing the whole color escape sequences:
The prompt starts with

```
[\e[\[1;37m\]\]...
```

The color escape sequence in this is `\e[1;37m`. So the escape character `\e`, and the `[` are outside. At least the `[` will be counted as visible. Also, there are two closing `\]` - it may not cause a problem, but is at least confusing - they can not be nested.
The correct way to write it is:

```
[\[\e[1;37m\]...
```

The other color escape sequences have the same problem.

Comment: I moved my .bashrc file to Ubuntu and some strange problem appeared again. http://postimg.org/image/7auk9ziex/ - here is a screenshot and problematic sign is that one yellow in the end of the first line. If you pay attention, there are two signs in one slot - that some strange one and '~'. What is the problem? How can I help? .bashrc is still in my repo in github - https://github.com/pt12lol/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

You should modularize this some - it would make it much easier to track:

```
CS='\[\033[1;3' CE='m\]'
WT=${CS}7${CE} LB=${CS}6${CE} PR=${CS}5${CE} \
DB=${CS}4${CE} YL=${CS}3${CE} GN=${CS}2${CE} RD=${CS}1${CE} 
CE='\[\033[m\]' CS=
```

Now you do your things:

```
# login and computer name                                                      
PS1="[${WT}\u${CE}@${GN}\h${CE}] "

...
```

And so on.. You see? It's a little easier to tell what's going on that way.