# Yellow appears as brown in konsole

Tags: terminal, colors, konsole

For some reason, the yellow color color ([ANSI Esc. code 33](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)), appears for normal fonts as orange/brownish in my terminal (yakuake, konsole).
For example, the command `echo -e "\\033[33mhello world\\033[0m"` returns an orange/brownish text `hello world`.  Bold yellow, however, appears as expected.  In the following, small, sccreenshot, the hostname is on top of a yellow background, which is the escape code `\e[43m`.

[image: <code>echo -e</code> examples in the terminal]

Another example, is the output of the command `terminal-colors -o`. It gives the output as seen in the larger screenshot below.

[image: <code>terminal-colors -o</code>]

I work with Funtoo-Linux and KDE. Though I have set some transparency (23%) I don't think this is a misleading of the eye issue. **How can I troubleshoot this?**

### Relevant details

- In Funtoo, the default `bashrc`, under `/etc/bash/`, contains:

  ```
  38:# Set colorful PS1 only on colorful terminals.
  63:            PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\]'
  65:            PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] '
  ```
- `echo $TERM` returns `xterm-256color`
- `echo $PS1` is set to

  ```
  \[\e[0;30m\e[45m\] \u \[\e[0;35m\e[43m\] \[\e[0;30m\e[43m\]@\H \[\e[0;33m\]\[\e[0;32m\] \w\a\[\e[0;32m\] → \[\e[0m\]
  ```
- the font used is irrelevant, as I have tried various ones
- if useful, `dircolors` returns:

  ```
  LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.pdf=00;32:*.ps=00;32:*.txt=00;32:*.patch=00;32:*.diff=00;32:*.log=00;32:*.tex=00;32:*.doc=00;32:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';
  ```

  export LS_COLORS
- strangely, there is a table in the post [BASH Shell: Change The Color of My Shell Prompt Under Linux or UNIX](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/), which describes the color code `0;33` as `Brown`!

---

**Update**

Perhaps more useful for 256 colors, is the output of `terminal-colors -cn` (or other parameters). In the screenshot below, the yellow background has been correctly set:

[image]

Comment: This command `echo -e "testing \033[30;48;5;226mCOLOR1\033[m"` however (see [Using ANSI Color Codes to Colorize Your Bash Prompt on Linux](http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux)), works fine == black on yellow. So, maybe it is brown rightly, after all?

Comment: I think this is traditional behavior.  I seem to recall that with old EGA/VGA hardware, the standard palette was set so that "yellow" was an ugly shade of brown.

Comment: This [Note 11 in ANSI escape code, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#cite_note-11) and this one [Note 12 in ANSI escape code, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#cite_note-12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8 standard colors numbered 1 through 8 officially contains primary and secondary colors (black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white), but there is considerable variation: many terminals don't show primary colors, but instead show variants thereof. Yours shows the following RGB values:

```
383a3a ff3950 00b226 c56227 022bab fd16de 00b5ae aeb2b3
```

while nominal values with roughly similar brightness would be

```
000000 a00000 00a000 808000 0000a0 800080 008080 808080
```

There is considerable variation on all colors, not just on the one for which you choose to give a different name. Yellow does however have a tradition of being made more brownish because actual yellow tends to be poorly contrasted on a white background (and sometimes blue is made more grayish to be better-contrasted on a black background).

You can change the colors used by Konsole if they bother you. In the profile settings, go to the “Appearance” tab and either choose from one of the profiles or make up your own. You can even make the colors resemble nothing like the standard ones if you wish, though that may be confusing at times.

Comment: See also comments above (links to [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) -- relevant?

Comment: Curious: where did you extract "my" RGB values from? The screenshot?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Yes, specifically the [section on colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). As you can see, there's quite a broad variation in the “yellow” color, ranging from brown to orange to yellow-green (to my perception). I extracted your RGB values from the screenshot.

Comment: Respect. No wonder the 253K.

Comment: My prompt received its yellow now :-): `echo $PS1
\[\033[s\]\[\e[0;38;5;232m\[\[\e[48;5;5m\] \u \[\e[0;38;5;5m\[\[\e[48;5;11m\] \[\e[0;38;5;232m\[\[\e[48;5;11m\]@\H \[\e[0;38;5;11m\[\[\]\[\] \[\e[38;5;117m\]\w\a →\[\]`

Comment: The previous PS1 was faulty. Fixed: `PS1="\e[0m\[\e[0;38;5;232m\]\[\e[48;5;5m\] \u \[\e[0;38;5;5m\]\[\e[48;5;11m\] \[\e[0;38;5;232m\]\[\e[48;5;11m\]@\H \[\e[0;38;5;11m\]\[\e[48;5;0m\]\[\e[0m\] \[\e[\e[0;38;5;6m\]\w\a \[\e[1;38;5;5m\]→\e[0m"`. I am looking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28827/13011 since there are still some mess-ups some times when going back and forth through the history.

Comment: A somewhat related _**Note:** The S-Lang library requires you to use the lightgray and brown keywords instead of white and yellow when setting this variable._ from [mutt's manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html).

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this, if you're using X11/Xorg, I would start by requesting `xrdb`:

```
xrdb -query
```

It will display all non-default values.

`~/.Xresources` or `~/.Xdefaults` files can customize your terminal colors. It can be customized in a specific application file in `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults/` directory as well.

For instance, on my box where I have my own `~/.Xresources` in order to change cyan color to purple in my Xterm, `xrdb -query` tells me:

```
xterm*color6:   purple3
```

Comment: This would be a correct answer for xterm, but the asker isn't using xterm, he's using konsole, which doesn't use X resources.

Answer (score 0):

Konsole appears to have [color issues](https://askubuntu.com/a/843850/42522), so i just used bright yellow (93) instead of brown "yellow" (33):

```
timmerman@dev:~/Downloads$ export PS1='\u@\h:\[\e[93m\]\w\[\e[m\]\$ '
```

[image: Konsole on Debian showing brown "yellow" (33) vs bright yellow (93).]