# Bash characters staying when browsing history

Tags: bash, terminal, command-history, prompt

When holding `k` or holding `up`, previously entered commands are shown, but at some point, the first 10 characters of a command longer than 10 characters stay. This is not always the first command longer than 10 characters encountered, but pressing `ctrl+c` and holding `up` again causes the same characters to stay.

```bsh
$ echo test
test

$ echo thisisalongstring
thisisalongstring

# pressing `up` twice
$ echo thisiecho test # should be `echo test`
test
# even though `echo thisi` is shown, it is not executed
```

Is there a way to fix this?

I didn't change anything in `~/.bashrc` (except appending `PS1='test '` for testing).

```
# this is the default ubuntu prompt
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

- This happens both in gnome-terminal and konsole.
- I tried appending `PS1='test '` and `PS1=''` to `~/.bashrc`, which contain no non-printable characters, but this still happens.
- Executing `PS1=$PS1` or `PS1=$(echo $PS1)` doesn't work.
- Manually pasting the code above into the terminal solves this problem, but I have no idea why.

  - Echoing `$PS1` after launching the terminal yields the same result as echoing `$PS1` after manually pasting.
  - Executing `. ~/.bashrc` causes the prompt to revert to being bugged.

---

This question sounds similar to the already solved [Why is my bash prompt getting bugged when I browse the history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/why-is-my-bash-prompt-getting-bugged-when-i-browse-the-history), but this also happens when no non-printable characters are present in `PS1`.

Comment: What shell are you using? This doesn't happen on my system (alacritty).

Comment: I tried it on gnome-terminal and konsole

Comment: At a guess there is a missing close-escape sequence.

Comment: But it still happens if PS1 is an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works without changing `PS1`:

```bsh
custom_prompt(){
    # default ubuntu prompt
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=custom_prompt
```